# It seems like Oracle silently restarts my procedure

Tags: oracle

I write a procedure to construct a report on OLAP Oracle server.
It works for some time.
Also after every operation I call autonomous_transaction log procedure to log my steps.
I dont use exception handling, so if something gone wrong, the procedure will failed.

But sometimes I see that in the middle of procedure it runs again! There no other processes which can run/rerun my procedure.
But other processes my drop/truncate/drop partitions.

Is it possible that Oracle restarts my procedure again absolutely SILENTLY - with no exception raising?

Answer (score 0):

Not likely. It is possible that your procedure is being run more than you realize? How does the procedure get run?